# make generic types in code variable

Tags: c#, generics

I want to  create a container class which works like a kind of Directory, but with multiple keys and the possibility to assign several values to one key. The number of possible keys should be variable. I want to do that through creating for every key-Type in inputTypes a new Dictionary which contains the key and the index of the value in the values' list.

```
    class SampleContainer<Tvalue>
    { 
      public SampleContainer(params Type[]inputTypes)
      {
          foreach(Type t in inputTypes)
          {
             ls.Add(new Dictionary(t,int));//won't compile 
          }
          values=new List<Tvalue>();
      }
       List<Dictionary< ???,int>> ls;/*object as ??? doesn't work,
                                       what to fill in to keep it "generic"*/
       List<Tvalue>values;
    }
```

Comment: You are doing it back to front. Create a `Dictionary<KeyType, List<ValueType>>` instead.

Comment: Do you mean multiple _keys_ or multiple key _types_.  So you want a `Dictionary<{Fruit or Animal},List<int>>`?

Comment: How about a `Dictionary<Type,Dictionary<object,List<int>>>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
        List<IDictionary> ls = new List<IDictionary>();
        ls.Add(typeof(Dictionary<,>).MakeGenericType(typeof(int), typeof(bool))
                                    .GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes)
                                    .Invoke(null) as IDictionary);
```

There are side-effects though, the `IDictionary` interface uses `object` key/value pairs. It may also cause boxing when attempting to retrieve a value (because it returns object types).

Maybe somebody can think of a really neat way to do it and keep the strong typing, but this is the closest I can think to come to what you are asking to do.

Comment: seems to work, recenty testing it, will mark it as solution when it finally works and is tested. Thanks.